# Split pandas dataframe column based on the pipeline symbol

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which has a single column named Category. I want to split this Category column into 4 separate columns named A, B, C, D based on the pipeline symbol "***||***"

Sample input: df['Category'] = Operations||Modification||Bank||Bank Process

Sample output:

df['A'] = Operations

df['B'] = Modification

df['C'] = Bank

df['D'] = Bank Process

I have looked up many answers on stack overflow but none are working for me. I have tried the following code:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] = df['Category'].str.split("||", expand = True)
```

But it gives the error: Exception has occurred: ValueError
Columns must be same length as key

Comment: You should escape the characters: `df['category'].str.split(r'\|\|', expand = True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your version of Pandas is running `str.split` with regex mode enabled.  In that case, you would need to escape the pipes:

```py
df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]] = df["Category"].str.split(r'\|\|', expand=True)
```

Or, you also could explicitly turn off regex mode:

```py
df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]] = df["Category"].str.split("||", expand=True, regex=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pipe has a special meaning in regex, you need to escape it or declare that you are not using a regex by setting `regex=False` in [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]] = df["Category"].str.split('||', regex=False,
                                                    expand=True)
```